# Show all Duplicate value of a specific column in mysql

Tags: mysql

```
id name phone
1     google 5689
2       msn  63699
3       google 78972
4       yahoo  20144
```

I want to show the result like this

```
id name phone
1     google 5689
3       google 78972
```

Comment: A subquery is unnecessary, but I think you'll need a join. What's wrong with using JOIN?

Comment: For joining I need another table, but right now I don't have another table for joining. So I want a SQL query without using joining.

Comment: You don't need another table to do a self join. See my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select *
from ax
where name1 in (select name1 from ax group by name1 having count(name1)>1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a subquery to do this:

```
select t.*
from yourtable t
inner join (
    select name
    from yourtable
    group by name
    having count(id) > 1
) t1 on t.name = t1.name
```

Comment: With out joining is it possible?